# How do I assert that an inner function was called with jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a class style declaration with javascript in my app and I need to test that an inner method was called.

The structure is like this....

```
angular.module("MyApp").factory('myClass', ['$rootScope', function (rootScope) {


    function active(type) {
        //how do I see if this method was called if cleartools public method is called?
    }


    return {
        active: active,
        clearActives: function() {
            active('');
        }
    }

}]);
```

How do I see if function active() was called if clearActives() is called?

Comment: Aren't you also exposing it as a public method?

Comment: Sorry I see, I am exposing an alternative use but encapsulating it....ClearActives() means something, Active('') does not....

Comment: My thinking was that since they refer to the same function the calls would track appropriately, but in my testing they do not. Bummer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by checking the caller function name, which would require you to name your functions

```
function active(type) {
    var callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
    if(callerName == "clearActives") {
        //do something
    }
}
return {
    active: active,
                  //Names the function
    clearActives: function clearActives() {
        active('');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cy5bb6zq/)